# JDBC MySQL multiple connection, which one is the best?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I have thread that use mysql connection. That thread will be multiply so I will have multi thread. This is summary of my thread.

```
public class t extends Thread{
...
run() {
// i will do database update here
}
...
}
```

I will have about 10.000 records and this records will be processed by 5 threads. So if update process finished, the thread will be re-used. 
I have 3 options for my problem :

1. create single connection and use it in every thread
2. for every thread, I create new connection (in the thread), and close it if thread finished.
3. create multiple-connection for each thread (outside the thread) and give it to thread when needed

Which one is faster?

Comment: I will go with 1st option

Comment: It depends on record processing time. Would it be fast or would it take some time?

Comment: It depends on how fast a thread can serve out SQL queries to the database. If it's going to be many queries in quick succession, it's better to have each thread having a dedicated DB connection.

Comment: I would try working with one thread and one connection and making sure it's too slow before going down a more complicated and error prone route, this could be a premature optimisation

Answer (score 1):

I think that each thread having own JDBC connection is best from performance reasons, because there is no synchronization overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for using some ORM/JPA implementation like **Hibernate** and/or use some kind of connections pool for automatic connection management.

Comment: I used to use Proxool, it was great JDBC pool.

Comment: IMHO one of the best JDBC connection pools is the one developed by the Apache Tomcat project (it's standalone though): https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html